# Sending a request to google direction API to get a path

Tags: android, json

I copied this entire class which sends a route request to google direction API. 
The function of this class returns in the form of JSON the path between two given points in the url.

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            json = sb.toString();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.d("JSON_RUTA", json);
        return json;

    }
}
```

For an unknown reason, in the line `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);` the app crashes, I understand that this is the main line where the request is sent to the server, but I have no idea why this is happening, I would be happy if you help me, thank-you very much.

Comment: are you sure you pass any day in url?

Comment: Yes, this is the function:

Comment: I bet on NetworkOnMainThread

Comment: `Unknown reason` meaning there is no error whatsoever, but somehow you figured something happened there?

Comment: yes, there is no errors in the code, but when I debuged it in this line the app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the first comment on the question, Yes, this is the function:

```
public String makeURL (double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog ){
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        urlString.append("?origin=");// from
        urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString
                .append(Double.toString( sourcelog));
        urlString.append("&destination=");// to
        urlString
                .append(Double.toString( destlat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString( destlog));
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
        return urlString.toString();
    }
```

Comment: let try put your calling  web service inside Thread , if you got error please put your error stack here